# Google Sheets time in one cell cost in another

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

In Google Sheets, I want to be able to calculate a dollar amount based on the time of day entered.

I'd like to enter the time in one cell and have the formula in another cell calculate the cost.

These are the time ranges:

- 2:36-3:05 $3
- 3:06-3:35 $6
- 3:36-4:05 $9
- 4:06-4:35 $12
- 4:36-5:05 $15
- 5:06-5:30 $18

Below is an example showing the result I want:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Time** | **Result** |
| **2** | 3:30 | $ 6.00 |
| **3** | 4:00 | $ 9.00 |
| **4** | 2:37 | $ 3.00 |

How can I perform this calculation?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]!   We'd love to help you but you ned to add more info. It seems like you may be looking for a simple [IF function (link)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en).  Checkout that link and see if it helps.   If you need more help [Edit] the question to include sample data and expected results.  Also include the formula you are struggling with and let us know what did/didn't work and any errors you encountered.  If you want to get the most out of this site, take the quick site [Tour] and review [ask].

Answer (score 0):

**Spoiler**

> =VLOOKUP(A2, $D$2:$E$7, 2)     // Basic
>  
>  =ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A2:A4, D2:E7, 2))    // Array
>  
>  =IFNA(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, D2:E7, 2)))    // Error Handling

#### VLOOKUP

This is an excellent candidate for the [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en) function which looks for a value in the first column of a range, then returns the value in the same row, but in the column you specify.

It also supports approximate matches which is great for your needs. If your lookup table is sorted by time (ascending)[VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en) will find the largest match that is less than or equal to the lookup value.

**Syntax**
 `=VLOOKUP(search_key, range, index, [is_sorted])`

#### Assumptions

All variations assume the following:

1. `D2:E7` is the range containing your lookup table (rate sheet):

   - `D2:D7` contains start times (column 1 of the range)
   - `E2:E7` has the rate for each start time (column 2 of the range)
2. `A2:A` contains the time(s) you want to check
3. `B2:B` contains the formula result(s).

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Time** | **Cost** |  | **Increment** | **Rate** |  |
| **2** | 3:35 | $ 6.00 |  | 2:36 | 3 |  |
| **3** | 3:00 | $ 3.00 |  | 3:06 | 6 |  |
| **4** | 3:45 | $ 9.00 |  | 3:36 | 9 |  |
| **5** |  |  |  | 4:06 | 12 |  |
| **6** |  |  |  | 4:36 | 15 |  |
| **7** |  |  |  | 5:06 | 18 |  |

#### 1. Basic Formula

This is the kind of formula that you copy down into other rows, so the range is absolute to stop it from changing when copied: `$D$2:$E$7` vs. `D2:E7`

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, $D$2:$E$7, 2)
```

#### 2. ARRAYFORMULA

The ARRAYFORMULA function enables a single VLOOKUP formula to return the results for multiple rows.  The **search_key** argument is changed to the range `A2:A4`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A2:A4, D2:E7, 2))
```

#### 3. IFNA

If you wrap the formula in the IFNA function, you don't need to worry about blank rows and can also use an infinite range such as `A2:A`.  Any new rows of times you add would be automatically calculated:

```
=IFNA(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, D2:E7, 2)))
```

[image]